# What is zero choose one?

Tags: combinatorics

Algebraically it comes out to be undefined- but if I have zero elements, and I'm asked to pull elements from it, this should just be zero, right?

Comment: Algebraically, $$\binom{n}{k} = \begin{cases}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} &, 0 \leqslant k \leqslant n\\ \quad 0 &, \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$ it's defined as $0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combinatorically speaking, you are absolutely right. There is no way to choose $1$ element from an empty set, so $\binom01=0$. It's a good idea to keep in mind that we do not always have $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.$ That formula only holds for **integers** $n,k$ such that $0\le k\le n$. If $n,k$ do not meet all those conditions, then $\binom{n}{k}=0.$

Answer (score 3):

One way to see this is with the binomial expansion,
$$
(1+x)^{\alpha}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{{\alpha}\choose{k}}x^k.
$$
Since $(1+x)^{0}=1$, we must have ${{0}\choose{0}}=1$ and ${{0}\choose{k}}=0$ for $k>0$.

Comment: If for example $\alpha=-1$ you get something like my interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

There is an interpretation of ${x \choose k}$ for positive integer $k$ but general $x$ as $$\frac{x \times (x-1) \times \cdots \times (x-k+1)}{k!}$$ which would give ${0 \choose 1}=0$.

Indeed it gives ${0 \choose k}=0$ for positive integer $k$, and ${n \choose k}=0$ for positive integers $n$ and $k$ with $n \lt k$. This corresponds to the combinatorial interpretation.

In this interpretation ${x \choose 0}$ is typically the *empty product*, namely $1$. This includes ${0 \choose 0}$.

What is different is that this interpretation of ${x \choose k}$ gives something non-zero for fractional or negative integer $x$.

Answer (score 2):

The graphic of the $\Gamma$ or factorial function can be found [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Gamma_plot.svg/600px-Gamma_plot.svg.png) : notice how it diverges towards $\pm\infty$ for each negative integer. Indeed, $$n!=\frac{(n+1)!}{n+1}\iff(-1)!=\frac{(-1+1)!}{-1+1}=\frac{0!}{0}=\frac10=\pm\infty$$ $$C_0^1=\frac{0!}{1!(0-1)!}=\frac1{(-1)!}=\frac1{\pm\infty}=0$$

Comment: There is no «indeed» here: your divisions by zero or (worse) by the non-number «$\pm\infty$» are no proof whatsoever of anything :-)

Comment: So $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\neq0$ , and/or $\lim_{n\to0}\frac1n\neq\infty$ ?

Comment: Perhaps worth noting: $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$ for all positive integers $n,$ and the function has a vertical asymptote at all *nonpositive* integers. You might want to adjust your answer slightly to reflect this. Another thing I think is *definitely* worth noting: your answer would suggest, for example, that $\binom{3/2}{1}=3/2,$ but there is no such thing as a set with $3/2$ elements, so $\binom{3}{2}=0.$

Answer (score 0):

It is zero.  You cannot draw a sample of size 1 out of a set of size 0.